# sender id temperror hotmail.com

Tags: domain-name-system, spf, email

I am on vps and trying send mail. all is ok except hotmail

I search some and it seems, i am jumping on providers local ips:

> "Received: by 10.236.102.139 with SMTP id d11cs133207yhg; Tue, 19 Jul 2011 04:48:51 >-0700 (PDT)
>
> Received: by 10.68.28.8 with SMTP id x8mr8066589pbg.146.1311076131217; Tue, 19 Jul 2011 >04:48:51 -0700 (PDT)"

and http://www.openspf.org/Why says:

> "An SPF-enabled mail server rejected a message that claimed an
>   envelope sender address of yourhost.net.
>
> An SPF-enabled mail server received a message from
>   XXX.sub-XXX-XX-XX.myvzw.com (XXX.XXX.XX.XXX) that claimed an envelope
>   sender address of mydomain.com.
>
> However, the domain mydomain.com has declared using SPF that it does
>   not send mail through XXX.sub-XXX-XXX-XX.myvzw.com (XXX.XXX.XX.XXX).
>   That is why the message was rejected."

finally my spf TXT record is:

> v=spf1 mx -all

What should I do next?
Thanks

Comment: Would you tell me wich mail address did you write to in order to get support? We have been facing this problem since a few weeks and we can't find any solution or any "human" on hotmail side. Thanks!.

Comment: Sorry that mail was in my old mail box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I emailed hotmail guys about the issue and have quick reply "we are aware the issue, several emails we received from other guys". then i wait several days and decided to google app mail. voila issue solved